# Is there a Solana program that can facilitate the sale of an NFT to the highest bidder?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, nft, program, spl-token-program

There is a use case where an NFT might be available in an auction where multiple bidders compete with SOL to win the NFT when the auction time expires. However, if an application is designed to trust that the winning bidder will pay, often the payment will not happen and the auction either goes to the second bidder or falls through entirely. This is messy and something I would expect a modern blockchain program to be able to solve.

Does the Solana blockchain have a way to act as an intermediary? First it would lock the seller's NFT, then enforce the presence of the bidder's SOL, keeping it locked when they place the bid, and releasing it if they get outbid or sending it to the seller in exchange for the NFT if they win. That would be extremely useful.

What kind of things are possible along these lines for a Solana program?

Comment: Have you looked into the metaplex auction house program? https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/auction-house/

Comment: Wow, that is impressive. It looks like that is the answer. Thanks!